# swift Увеличить рисуемую фигуру во все стороны

Tags: swift

У меня есть массив точек (`CGPoint`), по этим точкам я рисую линии на изображении, а именно: у меня есть на изображении фигура (условно, квадрат) и по заданным точкам я рисую фигуру (условно, тоже квадрат) внутри квадрата на изображении, точки заданы так, что бы пройти по внутренним границам квадрата.

Проблема в том, что я немного не верно рассчитал сами точки и между внутренней границей квадрата (на самом изображении) и рисуемой мной линией (по точкам) остается пространство. Можно ли как-то сместить на пару позиций массив точек (`CGPoint`), что бы рисуемая мной линия и внутренняя граница квадрата соприкасались ? или тут только нужно заново определить новый массив точек, что бы уже соприкасались ?

Что бы не пересчитывать точки, я пытался задать, к рисуемой мной линиям, обводку (`Stroke color`) (я пытался тем самым добить пространство между моей линией и границей квадрата) и все было бы ок, но вот обводка на 50% с внутренней стороны моей линии и у меня не получается сделать ее только с внешней. Мб вы поможете мне с этим

```
func draw(points: [CGPoint], image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    context.setLineWidth(5.0)

    context.beginPath()
    var oldPoint = points[0]
    context.move(to: oldPoint)
    for index in 1...points.count-1 {
        context.addLine(to: points[index] as CGPoint)
        oldPoint = points[index] as CGPoint
    }
    context.addLine(to: points[0])
          
    context.closePath()
    
    UIColor.init(rgb: 0xe1dfdf).setStroke()
    UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4).setFill()
    
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    context.fillPath()
    
    guard let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return resultImage
}
```

Comment: тут зависит от того, что для вас будет проще и удобнее - масштабировать массив точек, но для этого придется дописывать логику, или изначально делать фигуру немного больше

Comment: @schmidt9 для меня заново считать точки является адом, тк по факту их очень много, потому это на последнем месте. Если есть возможность как-то программно решить проблему, то будет круто! 
а как можно масштабировать массив точек ? я заступорился на момент определения : для какой точки нужно прибавить n, а для какой отнять n, что бы в итоге во все стороны ее расширить

Comment: у меня есть решение масштабирования на C++, к сожалению там довольно много кода и у меня нет времени его переписывать на свифт, если нужно, я могу его куда-нибудь скинуть, можете сами переписать или адаптировать для использования в свифте

Comment: @schmidt9 да, спасибо большое. Скиньте на любой хостинг, например, https://pastebin.com

Comment: https://gist.github.com/schmidt9/534361ab8d504ccd6b92bbd3b2c22acd

Comment: @schmidt9 спасибо,не подскажите пару моментов : для TextUtils какую библиотеку нужно импортировать ?  и ругается на подобный вид функций `bool
    MathUtils::polygonIsClockwise(const std::vector<Point> &points, int &error, bool useInvertedY)`

Comment: Метод где используется TextUtils можно убрать и целом отредактировать вид методов под себя, я туда из проекта скопировал как есть

Comment: @schmidt9 спасибо огромное, работает ! 95% процентов случаев правильно масштабирует, оформите, как ответ

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать, в каких случаях неправильно, тк я сам использую этот код в приложении. Можете скинуть например массив точек, когда по-вашему код работает неверно?

Comment: @schmidt9 https://pastebin.com/H8492fxm

Comment: в основном, все работает, как надо, из 25 фигур 4 не верно переделало (вместо их увеличения наоборот уменьшило)

Comment: а вы параметр верно передаете в `scalePointsByInset(const std::vector<Point> &points, double inset, bool useInvertedY)`? Для увеличения фигуры inset должен  быть отрицательным

Comment: @schmidt9 если я поставлю inset отрицательным, то теперь из 25 фигур только те 4 будут увеличены (которые были уменьшены при положительном inset), а остальные 21 - будут уменьшены

Comment: я могу сделать обработку для определенных фигур использовать отрицательный inset, но звучит не очень )

Comment: у Вас такие же значения точек получились ? при подствке моих с примера ? мб я не верно алгоритм переписал. Я его переписал на c# и на swift

Comment: я не проверял пока ваши примеры, но по идее inset должен работать единообразно всегда, отрицательный на увеличение и наоборот

Comment: @schmidt9 возможно, я не правильно переписал алгоритм, проверьте, когда будет время, мои примеры, если у вас те же результаты выдаст, то дело в самом алгоритме

Comment: вообще переписывать необязательно, по крайней мере для свифта, можно подключить С++ например через обертку на Objective C

Comment: @schmidt9 я никогда такое не делал и боялся подводных камней, надо как-то обединить cgpoint с свифта в с++ , или юзать класс, который вы дали, но там еще либы тянет за собой (из за которых я не смог скомпилить в с++ и решил переписать на шарп и свифт), потому решил переписать. Я могу в удобном для вас виде дать точки для теста, что бы вы легко импортировали в проект

Comment: я проверил код, который вам дал, на первом наборе ваших точек, и действительно, он дает неверный результат в данном случае, вероятно он больше подходит для более простых вещей, поэтому я использовал еще один подход, который у меня есть в проекте - вычисление центра точек и масштабирование на его основе, и там все корректно, если будет время, попробую его выложить

Comment: вот второй вариант https://gist.github.com/schmidt9/c332cab57e81f62f8a719958a6ed733a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подготовил [тестовый проект](https://github.com/schmidt9/ScalePointsTestSwift), где реализовано масштабирование вашего массива точек (я сдвинул их, вычтя 1000 из всех координат, чтобы уместить на экране).

Алгоритм такой - вычисляем для массива его границы по самым внешним точкам, получая выпуклый многоугольник, затем вычисляем для него центр, и затем уже на основе массива точек и полученного центра делаем масштабирование.

Проект на Swift, но вычисления я оставил на С++, для него сделал обертку на Objective C для конвертации данных между C++ и Swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: огромное спасибо! очень рад, что есть отзывчивые люди, которые всегда помогут

Comment: @user883884 взаимно, благодаря вам всплыли недоработки в моем коде